# Select distinct rows in MySQL

Tags: sql, select

i am experiencing a problem which i can't figure out why is causing me trouble.

I want to select all offers from a database with a DISTINCT statement, so every offer ID is pulled uniquely. Here's what i got in screenshot form on Navicat:

[Screenshot http://www.dreshar.com/sql.jpg](http://www.dreshar.com/sql.jpg)
http://www.dreshar.com/sql.jpg

For anyone who cant see the image, this is the select - where is my error?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
guf_offers.id as OfferId,
guf_offers.validfrom AS OfferValidFrom,
guf_offers.validtill AS OfferValidTill,
guf_offers.days AS OfferDays,
guf_offers.active,
guf_offers.roomtype1 AS OfferRoomtype1,
guf_offers.roomprice1 AS OfferRoomprice1,
guf_countries.caption AS CountryCaption,
guf_courts.caption AS CourtCaption,
guf_hotels.caption AS HotelCaption,
guf_hotels.id AS HotelId,
guf_hotel_images.image AS HotelImage,
guf_offer_types.caption AS OffertypeCaption,
guf_regions.caption AS RegionCaption,
guf_offers.hoteloncourse AS OfferHotelOnCourse,
guf_offers.wellnessspa AS OfferWellnessSpa,
guf_offers.18hole AS Offer18Hole,
guf_offers.topangebot AS OfferTopangebot
FROM guf_offers , guf_countries , guf_courts , guf_hotels , guf_hotel_images , guf_offer_types , guf_regions
WHERE guf_offers.country_id = guf_countries.id AND guf_offers.court_id = guf_courts.id AND guf_offers.hotel_id = guf_hotels.id AND guf_hotel_images.hotel_id = guf_offers.hotel_id AND guf_offers.offer_type_id = guf_offer_types.id AND guf_offers.region_id = guf_regions.id AND guf_offers.active = 1 AND STR_TO_DATE(guf_offers.validtill, '%d.%m.%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('29.04.2013', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

DISTINCT returns any distinct COMBINATION of columns.  For example, the first two instances of OfferId = 89 in your image shows a different value in the HotelImage column, so therefore those are DISTINCT results.

Comment: You are right - i understand. Is there a possibility to tell SQL only to select the first result so i would get only the first found image?

Comment: Yes there is, but you have to specify what you mean by the first result.

Comment: For example. for each result select the first found image in hotel_images to display on a result site

Comment: You can use the LIMIT clause, though I'm not sure that's best in this case.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Can you describe fully what you are doing with this data?  That will help us formulate the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want distinct ids, then you probably want to use a `group by`.  The query would look something like:

```
SELECT
guf_offers.id as OfferId,
guf_offers.validfrom AS OfferValidFrom,
guf_offers.validtill AS OfferValidTill,
guf_offers.days AS OfferDays,
guf_offers.active,
guf_offers.roomtype1 AS OfferRoomtype1,
guf_offers.roomprice1 AS OfferRoomprice1,
guf_countries.caption AS CountryCaption,
guf_courts.caption AS CourtCaption,
guf_hotels.caption AS HotelCaption,
guf_hotels.id AS HotelId,
guf_hotel_images.image AS HotelImage,
guf_offer_types.caption AS OffertypeCaption,
guf_regions.caption AS RegionCaption,
guf_offers.hoteloncourse AS OfferHotelOnCourse,
guf_offers.wellnessspa AS OfferWellnessSpa,
guf_offers.18hole AS Offer18Hole,
guf_offers.topangebot AS OfferTopangebot
FROM guf_offers , guf_countries , guf_courts , guf_hotels , guf_hotel_images , guf_offer_types , guf_regions
WHERE guf_offers.country_id = guf_countries.id AND guf_offers.court_id = guf_courts.id AND guf_offers.hotel_id = guf_hotels.id AND guf_hotel_images.hotel_id = guf_offers.hotel_id AND guf_offers.offer_type_id = guf_offer_types.id AND guf_offers.region_id = guf_regions.id AND guf_offers.active = 1 AND STR_TO_DATE(guf_offers.validtill, '%d.%m.%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('29.04.2013', '%d.%m.%Y')
group by guf_offers.id
```

The other columns are *arbitrary* values from different rows.  This uses an extension to the `group by` where columns can be in the `select` even when they are not in an aggregation function or in the `group by` clause.

By the way, you should learn to do your joins in the `from` clause using propoer `join` syntax.  It makes queries more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. What i am trying to do is the following : I need to put together a result page where i need to draw information from different tables such as image, country name, region name etc - what i need is :

List all Offers (guf_offers) and match the ids on the offers table with the other tables, for example guf_offers.hotel_id => guf_hotels.id and get the hotel name. 

Then i try to get a fitting image from the table guf_hotel_images by passing the id from guf_offers.hotel_id to guf_hotel_images.hotel_id  - the problem is there are many images for a hotel  -> loops